# MYSQL > Using yearweek() how to select past week

Tags: mysql

How can I select all records from the last week ( starting from Monday last week) ?

I am trying to use

`yearweek()` in my sql query but i was only able to select this week records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. First we need to get the last week Monday from current date, so we can use the following technique

Below will always give the Monday of the current week

```
mysql> select date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day) as d ;
+------------+
| d          |
+------------+
| 2016-09-19 |
+------------+
```

Now to get the Monday of the last week we can adjust the above as

```
mysql> select date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day), interval 7 day)  as d ;
+------------+
| d          |
+------------+
| 2016-09-12 |
+------------+
```

And finally to retrieve the data we can do as

```
select * from your_table
where 
date_column >= date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day), interval 7 day)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

Best is to handle the date calculation i.e. last week Monday on application level and then pass the value to the query.

Comment: Sorry I was lost in the example can you make it more clean.

can you give me on query ?

Comment: I use the last example and I got the total recoreds form last week and this week .. I only need to select from the last week

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.. and `I only need to select from the last week` is it from last week `Monday till Saturday` or `Monday till Sunday` ?

Comment: Monday till Sunday.

from 12-9 till 18-9 I have 200 record
from 19-9 till 21-9(today) I have 100 record

when I use your query I get 300 record, I should get 200 instead

Comment: Just change the where condition as `where 
date_column between date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day), interval 7 day) and date_add( 
date_sub(date_sub(curdate(), interval weekday(curdate()) day), interval 7 day),interval 6 day)`

Answer (score 1):

The [YEARWEEK](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_yearweek.asp) operator takes an mode option that lets you start the week on Monday.
Then just query for the YEARWEEK of NOW() minus 1

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE YEARWEEK(timestamp,1)=YEARWEEK(NOW(),1)-1
```

Answer (score 0):

See  [DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)

Not seeing you table structe, start with this and adjust to your needs

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK( curdate() )+ 7 DAY
```

Comment: thanks but this gives me records from 10 September until today , I need to select only between 12-18 September

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

date BETWEEN YEARWEEK(CURDATE()) AND CURDATE()-INTERVAL 7 DAY